# What is this plant that looks like red kale?

Tags: identification

In my garden a plant just popped up randomly and I don't know what it is. It came last year in my garden, and I was wondering till then. The leaves are dark green and the underside is a but purple as in the picture: [image: 1]

Comment: Did you make your own compost? Did it contain avocado pits, by any chance? Looks like avocado seedling.

Comment: Yeah, I put in avocados in my compost in my garden.

Comment: @benn I would like to upvote an answer! (And remind you that answers in comments are very much discouraged.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks very much like an avocado seedling. It happend to me last year that I had some avocado pits in my compost bin, and when I used the compost to mulch my garden the pits were still viable. From your comments I think it is likely also the case here. If you live in a temperate climate the plants will probably die somewhere in winter. However, I live in North-western Europe and my seedlings actually survived a pretty cold winter, so they are still in my garden now. They died back to the ground, but new shoots emerged late spring.

Comment: I live in North Carolina, so do you think they will die in the winter or will they survive? It goes to about 20-40ºF.

Comment: I think you'll need to go more south (Florida) to be save, but you can try. We had a very cold week in February this year (frost all day with pack of snow), and it survived!